# Is there a way to stop Eclipse (3.7) from messing up content of <xsd:documentation> tags?

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

If I write multi-line documentation in an XML schema using the properties view it creates `<xsd:documentation>` tags to contain it.

Whenever I format the file (CTRL+SHIFT+F) all lines but the first are indented and sometimes wrapped due to this indentation.

This indentation and wrapping effectively ruins every effort of generating a nice looking documentation from the file. Especially if I want to document a table of allowed values.

**Before format:**

```
<xsd:documentation>1st line of comment
2nd line is indented and also wrapped as it exceeds the max line length setting.
3rd line is just indented.
</xsd:documentation>
```

**After format:**

```
<xsd:documentation>1st line of comment
    2nd line is indented and also wrapped as it exceeds the max line 
    length setting.
    3rd line is just indented.
</xsd:documentation>
```

The "Format comments" option in Preferences -> XML -> XML files -> Editor does not help with the indentation. Increasing "Line width" on the same preferences page fixes wrapping but I really want the editor to NOT format my the contents of my documentation elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an xml atribute `xml:space="preserve"` to `xsd:documentation` to tell that spaces must be preserved. For example:

```
<xsd:documentation xml:space="preserve" >1st line of comment
    2nd line is indented and also wrapped as it exceeds the max line length setting.
    3rd line is just indented.
</xsd:documentation>
```

Comment: I prefer using this attribute rather than the added CDATA tag, it looks cleaner, it's self-explaining and I don't have to explicitly tell Eclipse to ignore CDATA wrapped text. My trick is to add all my multi-line text in a single line, use the format code in Eclipse and then add the xml:space attribute to preserve the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

"Format comments" option is for XML comments:

```
<!-- comment -->
```

That's why it's not working as you wish.

I do not understand what problem are you facing with setting "line width" option to max (in version 3.7 it is 999).

If your XML is:

```
<xsd:documentation>1st line of comment
    2nd line is indented and also wrapped as it exceeds the max line length setting.
    3rd line is just indented.
</xsd:documentation>
```

Then setting "line width" to 999 and formatting does not change your content. Unfortunately there is **no** option to turn width checking off (for example to set "line width" to 0).

**edit:**
it seems that when you use  <![CDATA[, Eclipse is not formating the content (at least indentation and line wrapping), example:

```
<root>
    <documentation><![CDATA[
                1st line of comment

                2nd line is indented and also wrapped as it exceeds the max line length setting.

                3rd line is just indented.
        ]]></documentation>
</root>
```

Comment: Sure I can set the line width but the problem is that I have written documentation in a specific format and Eclipse keeps reformatting it. Not only the line wrapping but also indentation is added. When I try to generate documentation from a tool such as XML Spy the documentation is poorly formatted, partly due to indentation added by Eclipse.

Comment: It is also the case that Eclipse itself, by formatting the documentation, makes the documentation look very strange in the properties editor.

Comment: I see, maybe you should try some plugins from [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/xml?page=1&mpc=true&mpc_state=) and find better XML editor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Yes I will probably try the XML Spy Eclipse integration the next time. At the time I asked the question I did not have the XML Spy license that is required for working with WSDL files. There seems to be no other solution unless I can find time to create my own patch for Eclipse and I don't see that happening anytime soon.

Comment: see my edited answer how to use <![CDATA[ maybe that's what you need, but you have to try if it meets your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Try using it like this:

```
<xsd:documentation><![CDATA[ 1st line of comment
2nd line is indented and also wrapped as it exceeds the max line 
length setting.
3rd line is just indented.]]></xsd:documentation>
```

But ALSO , try to set

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

in your file, if you are not already using it. New lines in xml can be problematic between ASCII and UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

Set the option "Preserve whitespace in tags with PCDATA content".

Comment: That really seems to be the thing to set. But it does not have any effect when I try it. Since my question was about editing an XML Schema file I also tested a plain XML file with this option set but I still get the same results. Have you tried the snippet from the question?

I have also noticed that the file reformats twice if I apply the format command twice. Doing it a third time does no additional changes.

Comment: This is because you don't have anything that tell eclipse that what is inside the documentation element is a PCData element, see [Eclipse bug 361708](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361708).